# JsonAPI - Updating the relationship for a resource

Tags: rest, api-design, json

I am having trouble understanding http://jsonapi.org/. Say, I have the following endpoints in my API for authors and articles.

> /authors
>
> /authors/:id/articles

If I wanted to fetch the details for a single article, I can use

> /authors/:id/articles/:id

which returns data that looks like

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "type": "articles",
  "data": {
    "attributes": {
      "title": "Programming in javascript.",
      "body" : "Some long text here..."
    },
    "relationships": {
      "author": {
        "data": {
          "id": "2",
          "type": "authors"
        },
        "links": {
          "self": "http://api.com/authors/2"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, if I want to update this article and change the author, the spec says I should use a PATCH. Should this PATCH request be made to

> /authors/:id/articles/:id
>
> /authors/:id/articles/:id/relationships/author

or

> /articles/:id
>
> /articles/:id/relationships/author

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change who the author is, that's a relationship on the article. You would patch `/articles/:id` and include the new author, as per [the spec](http://jsonapi.org/format/#crud-updating-resource-relationships).

Comment: Please remove the trailing period from the link :)

Comment: @SamChats Fixed!